# How to use Oxygen XML transformation to .docx using dita.pdf2 formatting template?

Tags: xml, xslt, docx, dita, oxygenxml

I made a custom template for dita.pdf2 which i set up in transformation parameters as "customization.dir".

I'm happy with how it's working, but now I need to use same customization to export document in DOCX format.

What are the easy ways to do it or should I start from scratch and use different scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reuse your pdf customization for the Ms Word output. The way in which you can customize the ooxml output is by creating a template ooxml file: https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml/wiki/Extending